# Prometheus query returns invalid value

Tags: prometheus

I'm looking into Prometheus and wrote a query to get the per core performance of the CPU on a Windows machine in percent using the metrics provided by the ***wmi_exporter***. But the graph has some negative values in it and I wonder why. Can someone take a look at the following query and tell me what I did wrong:

```
100 - (avg by (core) (irate(wmi_cpu_time_total{job="myjob", instance="myinstance", mode="idle"}[5m])) * 100)
```

Interestingly, the query does only produce these negative values on one of the two instances. Below is an image showing the issue:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It's probably due to a race condition, you can see similar-ish things on Linux sometimes too. If the time spent in a mode is incremented and seen in the wrong second, this is what happens.